# Waf and checking for frameworks

Tags: macos, frameworks, waf

Using the Waf build system, you are given the ability to check for specific libraries.  For instance, were I to build a project using OpenGL, I can write:

```py
cfg.check(
    features = 'c cprogram',
    lib      = 'opengl',
    uselib_store = 'GL'
)
```

and Waf will attempt to compile a minimal program using OpenGL to determine whether or not my system supports that library.  On OS X, "Frameworks" are also supported. So, in 'gcc', i could do:

```
gcc -framework 'opengl' ...
```

to compile a program.  In Waf, I can also do:

```py
bld(
    features = 'c cprogram',
    source   = 'src/main.cpp',
    target   = 'helloWorld',
    framwork = 'opengl'
)
```

which compiles 100% fine.  However, given an OSX system that has an OpenGL framework (framework in the OSX sense), but not a normal OpenGL library, the configuration will fail, because the "check" program cannot be compiled.  I'm assuming I'm missing something relatively simple, but is there a way to check for a specific system framework in OSX using Waf? So far I have been unable to find one.